# Emacs mode or validation tool to help detect errors in JSON files?

Tags: json, git, parsing, emacs

I want to ensure my [JSON](http://json.org/) file is properly formatted before git pushing. I use emacs; is there a mode that helps detect syntax errors? Otherwise, is there some parser/validator that I can setup to run on changed `.json` files?

*Example of syntax error: comma after the last value of an object.*

Thanks!

**EDIT: For security reasons, I won't copy-and-paste the JSON into third-party JSON validation websites.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using.

Just paste the below code into your directory's `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file. Then, `chmod +x` the file.

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".json$")
if [ "$files" = "" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

pass=true

echo "\nValidating Modified JSON Files:\n"

for file in ${files}; do
    result=$(jslint ${file} | grep "${file} is OK")
    if [ "$result" != "" ]; then
        echo "\t\033[32mJSLint Passed: ${file}\033[0m"
    else
        echo "\t\033[31mJSLint Failed: ${file}\033[0m"
        pass=false
    fi
done

echo "\nJSON Validation Complete\n"

if ! $pass; then
    echo "\033[41mCOMMIT FAILED:\033[0m Your commit contains JSON files do not pass . Please fix the JSLint errors and try again.\n"
    exit 1
else
    echo "\033[42mCOMMIT SUCCEEDED\033[0m\n"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [flymake-json](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-json) - based on JSONLint, you may find also useful [json-reformat](https://github.com/gongo/json-reformat).

Answer (score 1):

Flymake seems obsoleted nowdays. You can try flycheck + jsonlint.
What I did to make it work in json-mode (emacs 25.1.50, ubuntu 14.04):

1. install jsonlint: `sudo npm install jsonlint -g`
2. remove `json-jsonlist` value from `flycheck-disabled-checkers` emacs variable list.
3. add to emacs config something like that:

`(require 'flycheck) 
(flycheck-add-mode 'json-jsonlint 'json-mode)
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)`

And that works for me: errors in json are highlighed and navigated by 
`M-g M-n` keys. Of course there could be alternative better/simpler ways described in a huge [flycheck documentation](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: n.b. This answer was written in 2016, and flymake was completely rewritten for Emacs 26.1 which was released in 2018.  I can't vouch personally for JSON support (I've never tried it); but speaking generally, flymake is definitely *not* obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a pure elisp port of Go's JSON parser that will highlight the first syntax error: https://github.com/psanford/json-error-mode